# Angularjs Controller is not working when I place it in a seperate file

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a sailsJS application and using AngularJS for the front-end.

This is my `index.ejs` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
<!-- load socket.io, angularjs, filters, special fonts, jquery, bootstrap -->

<!-- Application JavaScript -->
<script src='/js/app.js'></script>
<script src='/js/controllers/indexCtrl.js'></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="indexController">
<div ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my `app.js` file

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'angular.filter']);

console.log('this is executing');
```

and this is my `indexCtrl.js` file

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('indexController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  console.log('check if its executing');
}]);
```

I'm not getting a console log from `indexCtrl.js` file but I am from the `app.js` file

This is my folder structure

```
 - Api

 - Assets 
    --> images
    --> js
         --> controllers
              -->indexCtrl.js
         --> dependencies
         --> directives
         --> services
         --> app.js
    --> styles
    --> templates
    --> views


 - Config

 - node_modules

 - tasks

 - views
    -->index.ejs
```

Comment: do you see any error on console, what is your route like?

Comment: there aren't any errors in the console,

Comment: since you are using ui-router define your routes and move the ng-controller and add that to a partial. Refer to [ui-router wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

Comment: I want to use that controller to manage the Facebook JavaScript SDK and the client's socket.io connection to the server, I will render the partial in the `<div ui-view>` element later

Comment: so unless you will click the ui-sref or the button that redirect your app to the controller you will not see the console log from you controller

Comment: but I attached the controller to the `<body>` element

Comment: did you set $stateProvider

Comment: yes, but I will render different views based on whether the user is logged into my app or not, to find out, I need this controller to execute.

Comment: I think you are missing the route...look at this [demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dd8Nk9PDFotCQu4yrnDg?p=preview) for ui-plunker and look at route config

Comment: Your source code seems abolutely correct. There must be a misspelling somewhere in your code that you haven't supplied to us. Why don't you provide a simple plunker? Just simple javascript. EJS isn't really needed for this.

Comment: The only peculiar thing is that you initialize the ng-app in the DOCTYPE tag. Don't know if this is correct. It should be initialized in the html tag like this: <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <body>
    ...
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: And you are missing the opening html tag completeley.

Comment: yea, I'm changing the structure of my website a little bit and up until now, it's never been a problem so I didn't pay attention to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something about your opening html tag doesn't feel right. I've never seen the `DOCTYPE` tag and `<html>` tag fused together like that. Try something like this instead :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  ...
  ...
</html>
```

A few other things you can check :

- In your browser's developper console, check to make sure the request for `/js/app.js` and `/js/controllers/indexCtrl.js` went through and didn't return any 404 (Network tab in Chrome and Firefox)
- Make sure there are no Javascript errors in the console

Note : the fact that you were seeing the console.log from App.js only means the Javascript file was being downloaded and interpreted, but not necessarily that your Angular app was starting correctly (because the console.log is placed outside of any Angular function).

Comment: I never really payed attention to that !DOCTYPE thing, I'm rearranging the components of my app and it was never a problem, until now. Thanks.